# javascript objects or arrays? what is this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function(property, res, err, result){
    var json = {};
    json[property] = result;
    res.json(json);
};
```

Okay, this is a function that will take the above parameters. When invoked it creates an Object called json, my question is about the next line I dont understand it at all, is the object then the list of properties? Please enlighten me.

Comment: We are out of match sticks to `enlighten` you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to set the properties on objects. Most times people use dot notation like this:

```
json.property = result;
```

But if the property name is a string (which is what will be passed in as the `property` argument), the way the object property is set is like this:

```
json[property] = result
```

For example if someone puts these arguments into the function ("name", blah, blah, "Sam"), what is actually happening in the line in question is:

```
json["name"] = "Sam"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
json.name = "Sam"
```

And results in an object named `json` that looks like this:

```
{
  name: "Sam"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are just setting the property of the object. Object properties can be accessed/set in different ways:

```
objectName.property          // person.age
```

or

```
objectName["property"]       // person["age"]
```

or, your case:

```
objectName[expression]       // x = "age"; person[x]
```